# AWS Lambda python boto3 dynamodb table scan - An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: ExpressionAttributeNames

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am writing a simple dynamodb table scan with a filter expression using the boto3 documentation
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.scan

I am getting this error:
{
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation:
ExpressionAttributeNames can only be specified when using expressions",
"errorType": "ClientError",
Code:
import boto3
import pprint
from pprint import pprint
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr

```
    dbresource =boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    def lambda_handler(event, context):

    tableobject = dbresource.Table('basicSongsTable')

    response = tableobject.scan(ExpressionAttributeNames={'artist': ':variableartist'},
                            ExpressionAttributeValues={':variableartist': {'S': 'Matt'}})

    pprint(response)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to `Scan` the table and return when the artist=Matt?

```
dbresource =boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    def lambda_handler(event, context):

    tableobject = dbresource.Table('basicSongsTable')

    response = tableobject.scan(
    ExpressionAttributeNames={'#a': 'artist'},
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':v': {'S': 'Matt'}},
    FilterExpression='#a=:v'
    )

    print(response)
```

More examples here: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/tree/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/python/WorkingWithScans

Comment: Thank You so much. I don't know why they made it so complex. we need 3 parameter to scan a table. Greatly appreciate Your response

Comment: I clicked on that Ok arrow. Isn't that accepted ? Let me know if I need to click on something else

Comment: I looked at Your github samples. Great resource. I hope You teach on Udemy